# Verifier rejected class software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin

I'm trying to run the code that I copy-pasted from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html), specifically this line

```
val region = Region.AP_SOUTHEAST_1
val s3 = S3Client.builder().region(region).build()
```

but everytime I run it, it will give me this error

> java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class
> software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient: void
> software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.lambda$LRMaF_8eLuzzpRjS-Ew4gJswCBw(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase) failed to verify: void
> software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.lambda$LRMaF_8eLuzzpRjS-Ew4gJswCBw(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase):
> [0x0] 'this' argument 'Reference:
> org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase' not instance of
> 'Reference:
> org.apache.http.client.methods.AbstractExecutionAwareRequest'
> (declaration of 'software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient'
> appears in
> /data/app/com.imincode.earthlings-Jxs426ZYpcjwZtg1zzKjkw==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.builder(ApacheHttpClient.java:133)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheSdkHttpService.createHttpClientBuilder(ApacheSdkHttpService.java:29)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.-$$Lambda$-cEpDqlhpsSVBRGa6lPjzgTy1tM.apply(Unknown
> Source:2)
> at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:211)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.loader.DefaultSdkHttpClientBuilder.buildWithDefaults(DefaultSdkHttpClientBuilder.java:41)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.lambda$resolveSyncHttpClient$5$SdkDefaultClientBuilder(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:274)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.-$$Lambda$SdkDefaultClientBuilder$mSpkyGAugx5W7tgD88eQuJnqvEs.get(Unknown
> Source:2)
> at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:263)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.resolveSyncHttpClient(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:274)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.finalizeSyncConfiguration(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:225)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.syncClientConfiguration(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:158)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3ClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultS3ClientBuilder.java:27)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3ClientBuilder.buildClient(DefaultS3ClientBuilder.java:22)
> at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.builder.SdkDefaultClientBuilder.build(SdkDefaultClientBuilder.java:129)

Comment: I have similar code, with only the addition of specified credentials, and I receive the same error.
S3Client.builder().region(Region.US_WEST_1).credentialsProvider(() -> new AwsCredentials() {...}).build()

Comment: If I specify a custom HttpClient, it removes this error, but then I'm running into a FileNotFound Exception (likely just an error for me, but included for reference).

Comment: did anyone figure this out? I'm having this error using their SesClient.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error working with timestream db. So in my case, timestreamWriteClient accepts ApacheHttpClient.Builder:

```
ApacheHttpClient.Builder httpClientBuilder =
            ApacheHttpClient.builder();

return TimestreamWriteClient.builder()
            .httpClientBuilder(httpClientBuilder)
            .overrideConfiguration(overrideConfig.build())
            .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
            .build();
```

And on runtime, when app tries to create apache client, I got this error. So during some investigations, I found, that I can use another HTTP client - UrlConnectionHttpClient and pass it to TimestreamWriteClient.Builder.

```
httpClientBuilder: UrlConnectionHttpClient.Builder = UrlConnectionHttpClient.builder()
```

But this client should be included separately:

```
implementation 'software.amazon.awssdk:url-connection-client'
```

You can add version, adding ":X.Y.Z" at the end, but I use BOM, so I don't know anything about versions:

```
implementation platform('software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.15.0')
```

So, I think, that you also can pass this HTTP client to your S3 service builder, like I'm doing this with timestreamWriteClient builder.